# Is there a way to have a std::map without declare the value type

Tags: c++, c++11

I need a `std::map` container have something like:

`[ "a" => [ "a1" => [ "a11" => 1, "a12" => 0 ], "a2" => 1 ] ]`

1. The key `"a1"` have a value of another `std::map`, but the key `"a2"` have a value of integer. In this situation, how can I declare the map?
2. Is there a way to change the value to another type? For example, if I want to change the value of `"a12"` to a `std::vector`?

Thanks.

Comment: Some simple advice, it is much easier to do this with dynamic languages like python and ruby. Static typing doesn't lend itself to this problem. There are many possible solutions but they all involve embedding types in the application code, Probably unsuitable.

Comment: @ceorron Thanks, yes it is much easier to do this in python and ruby. Actually, I got this problem when I was trying to translate a python code to c++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do this straight away. Consider using some type-erasure device, peferably type-safe and well-understood, like `boost::variant` or `boost::any`. Otherwise, you can craft a `value` class that contains an opaque heap-allocated buffer (an old-school `void*`) and you are supposed to cast it to a type depending on the value of an `enum` field.

Answer (score 1):

when using std::map you need to specify value type. If you want to map to objects of different types I think you have two possibilities:

Define a base class for the value and declare a

```
std::map<int, base_class_t *>
```

map or, better a

```
std::map<int, shared_ptr<base_class_t>>
```

Then you can insert different objects, all derived from base_class_t.

The outher options is map to a union. But I would not do that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to understand your question fully.What I got is that you want to insert different types of values. The first key will contain the "int Value" of another map pointed at by another key of that map. the second key will contain a plain integer. If that's the case why not use vector inside a map.

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> mymap;
std::vector <int> vec;
vec.push_back(5);
mymap.insert(make_pair(1, vec));
```

Further to this if your not sure about datatype. you can also use nested maps. for the second element just put a dummy key.

```
std::map<int, std::map<int,int>> mymap;
std::map <int, int> mappy;
mappy.insert(make_pair(0,5));
mymap.insert(make_pair(1, mappy));
```

Does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

> The key "a1" have a value of another std::map, but the key "a2" have a value of integer. In this situation, how can I declare the map?

You can't declare such map. All values of a map have the same type.

> Is there a way to change the value to another type? For example, if I want to change the value of "a12" to a std::vector?

You probably mean, "Is there a way to chage the **type** of a variable to another". The answer is no.

However, it is possible to define a type that can enclose data of any type inside. It's not exactly simple to implement, but you're in luck, Boost has implemented such type: `boost::any`. A map with such value type can then hold a value of any type enclosed in the `any` -object. I would recommend reconsidering your design so that you don't need to have objects of any type, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, each STL container type needs exact ONE type. For your idea you need a container type which can hold multiple types. For that you can use `http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/variant.html`

Answer (score 0):

I think, likely a partial template class with one parameter defined could be the answer to your problem, Something like this;

```
template <typename T>
class partialMap : public std::map<int,T>
{
};

int main()
{
  //vector example
  std::vector <int> vec;
  partialMap<std::vector<int>> _vecMap;
  vec.push_back(5);
  _vecMap.insert(make_pair(1, vec));
  //map example
  std::map<int,int> map;
  partialMap<std::map<int,int>> _mapMap;
  vec.push_back(5);
  _mapMap.insert(make_pair(1, map));
}
```

So, you might use indistinctly the same class with the first parameter predefined and the second one defined in function whatever you need.